# ¿Cuál es la lógica de +(new Date) en JavaScript y otros usos de '+'?

Tags: javascript

He visto algunas veces que el operador "+" se utiliza de otras formas diferentes a lo que yo tenia entendido era sumar dos valores, por ejemplo en el caso de:

```
+(new Date)
```

Que se usa comunmente para hacer el ***now***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De la forma en la que usted pregunta, el operador + se presenta como un operador unario, esto significa que sólo necesita un operando para realizar su labor. El operador de suma unaria precede su operando e intenta evaluarlo e intenta convertirlo (o forzarlo) a un tipo de dato numérico. Por ejemplo:

```js
console.log(+"3");
```

Obliga a Javascript a convertir el tipo de dato "3" (String) a numérico. Para otros tipos de datos diferentes a String, Javascript intenta llamar al método `valueOf()` or `toString()` del objeto y al String resultante lo intenta convertir en un número.

En este sentido, al usar el operador + al crear un objeto de tipo `Date` está invocando a la función `valueOf()` del mismo. De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf), esta función retorna el valor primitivo del objeto, que no es más un número que representa el número de milisegundos que han transcurrido desde un evento conocido como el EPOCH (la medianoche del 1 de enero de 1970 en UTC) hasta el momento de creación del objeto.

```js
console.log(new Date()); //Devuelve una representación en texto del objeto
console.log(+new Date()); //Representación primitiva.
```

El operador unario + se añade sólamente para garantizar que el tipo de dato devuelto sea un número entero. Esta implementación se usaba mucho antes de ES5, ya que era la forma 'estándar' de obtener los milisegundos transcurridos desde el EPOCH. Pero desde ES5 es preferible usar funciones como `Date.now()`, cuyo resultado es el mismo.

Comment: Como añadido a este gran ejemplo, destaca que también sería lo equivalente a: ```String(new Date) === Date()``` o ```Number(new Date) === +(new Date)``` o ```Number(new Date) === Date.now()```.